# How to load different css styles with query string parameter in Django

Tags: python, django

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^/pageId=yeti$', home, name='home'),
]
```

layout.html:

```
if(pageId == 'yeti'):    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/bootswatch/yeti/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />    


    <select class="form-control" id="themeLoader" onchange={% url '/pageId=yeti/' %}>
                    <option value="Yeti">Yeti</option>
                </select>
```

views.py:

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""


    pageId = ""
    if(request.GET.get('pageId')):
       pageId= "yeti"
    elif request.POST.get('pageId'):
      pageId = request.POST.get('pageId')      
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        context =
        {
            pageId : pageId,
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the django template language to direct logic flow in your template, layout.html

Here is a link to an if statement in django template language: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-if

Here is what your template should look like, using the django template language:

```
{% if pageId == "yeti" %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/content/bootswatch/yeti/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
{% endif %}       

<select class="form-control" id="themeLoader" onchange={% url '/pageId=yeti/' %}>
    <option value="Yeti">Yeti</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @sly_Chandan , are you seeing any errors in the django logs, or in the browser console? Have you verified that the `pageId` is being properly set in the context before render?

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for '/pageId=yeti/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

That's the error I am getting

Comment: ah, @sly_Chandan that means that django can't find the right view to direct to for the url you are supplying. Your URL conf is improperly configured. Have you followed the instructions set out [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#url-dispatcher)?

Comment: What URL are you trying to hit it with? Is it supposed to be your index url with a GET param for `pageId`? If that's right, you shouldn't be including the GET param in the pattern to match in urls.py. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against) for reference. So, you should remove the `pageId=yeti` from the url pattern

Comment: This is my Url  pattern
url(r'^$', home, name='home')]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131926/discussion-between-harry-wallace-and-sly-chandan).

Answer (score 0):

layout.html

```
{%  if pageId2 == "Cerulean" %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/bootswatch/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    {% endif %}

    {%  if pageId2 == "Cosmo" %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'app/bootswatch/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />
    {% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="Post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <select style="margin:5px;" class="form-control" id="themeLoader" name="themeLoader" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                            <option value="Select">Select Theme</option>
                            <option value="Cerulean">Cerulean</option>
                            <option value="Cosmo">Cosmo</option>        
                      </select>                        
                </form>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    """Renders the home page."""

    pageId = ""
    if(request.GET.get('pageId')):
       pageId= "Cerulean"

    elif request.POST.get('themeLoader'):
      pageId = request.POST.get('themeLoader')      
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html/',
        context =
        {
            'pageId2' : pageId,
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
```